# InvocationTargetException when trying to assign items to choicebox using javafx

Tags: java, javafx

The simple attempt to add choices to my choice box results in a `InvocationTargetException`. I don't really understand the reason of why this exception is thrown, so a explanation along with a soloution would be great! Here is my code in the FXMLDocumentController Class:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<?> pilot;

    public FXMLDocumentController(){  

         setMembersList();
    }


    private void setMembersList(){
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Item A");
        list.add("Item B");
        list.add("Item C");
        ObservableList obList = FXCollections.observableList(list);
        pilot.setItems(obList);
    }
}
```

Here is what I get...:

```
Exception in Application start method

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:367)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:305)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:894)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:158)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Using trial and error the exception is definitely thrown in the line `pilot.setItems(obList);` as it starts up without any exceptions when I get rid of this line.

Comment: Can you add your stackTrace ?

Comment: Can you post the rest of the stack trace? If you read it far enough down you should not need "trial and error" to see which line is throwing the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `FXML`-injected `ChoiceBox` will not be initialized at the time the constructor is called, so you will get a `NullPointerException` (`pilot` is `null`).

Instead, invoke your code from the `initialize()` method. I would also properly type your `ChoiceBox` and the `ObservableList`:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController {

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<String> pilot;

    public void initialize(){  

         setMembersList();
    }


    private void setMembersList(){
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Item A");
        list.add("Item B");
        list.add("Item C");
        ObservableList<String> obList = FXCollections.observableList(list);
        pilot.setItems(obList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that helpful answer and additional advice , totally works out!:)

Answer (score 1):

Remove your `ChoiceBox` object (basicly every object which is defined in your FXML file) initialization from constructor and place it in (best) `initialize` method.